# How to define specific marginal distributions (ARMA-GARCH) in the mvdc function from a copula package?

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to specify marginal distributions of the variables and fit copulas in order to find a dependence structure between those variables. I fit margins and find copulas. Then I am using mvdc from copula package to construct a multivariate distribution constructed from copula with specified margins. However, I do not know how to specify my marginal distributions inside that function.

I have copulas and margins with already estimated parameters. mvdc function gives an example with standard distributions such as normal, student etc. However, my marginals are specified as ARMA(1,1) - EGARCH(1,1) with student t distribution. My question is how to fit these ARMA-EGARCH marginals into mvdc?

- Marginal distribution ARMA(1,1)-EGARCH(1,1) with std

  ```
  spec11 = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1), include.mean = T), distribution.model = "std")
  ```

Then I estimate the parameters and check that this marginal fits the data well. Then I can fit the copula and calibrate the parameters. Let's say that the optimal copula is this one and in the next line I am trying to construct multivariate distr.

```
t.cop = tCopula(c(0.7863), dim = 2, dispstr = "toep", df = 7.36, df.fixed = T)
multi_distribution =  mvdc(t.cop, c("norm", "norm"),
                           list(list(mean = 0, sd =2), list(mean = 1, sd=3)))
```

I found one similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321894/copula-for-non-standard-distributions-in-r

However, it did not solve my problem. Is there any solution to this?